# Search by hash character using wildcard in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I'm using elasticsearch 6.0 and I want to look for all objects, starting from hash characted `#`. I execute the following query

```
    {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "wildcard" : {
          "message" : {
            "wildcard" : "#*",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

And I get null result. It seems like `#` char is special character in wildcard. Can you help me with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the field datatype that you used for `message`? By default `string` tokenizes the string, and characters like a hash are used for tokenization. If you want to use the hash for searching, then you could change the tokenizer to `whitespace`, see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html